# Data sent from node server using broadcast emit from another client is not able to be read by c++ socket io client

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, websocket, socket.io

**Node server**

```
'use strict';

const express     = require('express');
const app         = express();
const serverHttp  = require('http').Server(app); 
const io = require('socket.io')(serverHttp);

const port = 8081;

socket.on('JogCartesianButton', data => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('JogCartesianButton', data)
    console.log(data)
  })
serverHttp.listen(port, function() {  
    console.log("init!!!");    
});
```

**data** looks like this

```
{   
  q_value: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],  
  status: false,  
  joint: true,  
  cartesian: false,  
  freedrive: false,  
  button: true,  
  slider: false,   
  goto: false,  
  threed: false   
}
```

now im accepting this **data** from server in c++ client. By broadcast emitting it.

My c++ client code is below.

```
        sio::client io;
        io.set_open_listener([&]() {
            std::string nickName = "asdad";
            io.socket()->emit("key", nickName);
            io.socket()->on("JogCartesianButton", [&](sio::event& ev)
                    {
                       //Here how do i get the **data** from server
                    });
        });
        io.connect("http://localhost:8081/");
```

**How do i accept that data inside c++ which was broadcasted from node server.** 
**i tried ev.get_messages() 0x7ff174008130 this was the output, but need  { key : value } as output .**

Comment: _"but im getting some reference"_ What does this mean? Be more clear. Present a [mcve]

Comment: Hi i just made some changes, could you have a look at it.

Comment: The problem statement is still just _"but im getting some reference"_ (well, okay, the title also includes a _"i am not able"_)

Comment: Take a look at the [example](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/blob/master/examples/Console/main.cpp) in that repo. See how they subscribe to the event. Also take a look at [the definition of event_listener_aux](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/blob/master/src/sio_socket.h#L49)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica i changed it like u mentioned.

Comment: That's a bit better. How do you "get" 0x7ff174008130? What code you run to get it? Where do you see that result? Are you using `cout`? Again, you need to produce a [mcve].

Comment: You should also link to (or otherwise concretely identify) the library you're using.

Comment: im using orocos library

```
RTT::log(RTT::Warning)<<"Reding Socket: "<< ev.get_message()<<RTT::endlog();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is very incomplete, but something like the following should work: (taken from [this example](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/blob/master/examples/Console/main.cpp#L74))

```
io.socket()->on("JogCartesianButton", sio::socket::event_listener_aux([&](string const& name, message::ptr const& data, bool isAck, message::list &ack_resp) {
    string user = data->get_map()["name"]->get_string();
    int64_t age = data->get_map()["age"]->get_int();
    // Do something with user and age
}));
```

As I remarked in the comments, the `on()` method is polymorphic in its callback, and the `event_listener_aux` form is a bit more easy to use. Note that this example does zero error checking up front, so you should inspect every part of `data` using `message::get_flag` before you access it.

Comment: I edited out the data , and i want to send this data from server to client, could you help me out with the new data.

Comment: Attach a debugger, show a stack trace and inspect the data variable. I cannot "help you out" without any information about the crash.

Comment: thank you @botje . It worked. 
but q_value: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] this data i was not able to fetch it, tried using get->vector() ... in the end i sent it as 6 int variables.